# Amazon SES email spam marked

Tags: php, email, amazon-ses

I'm using Amazon SES to send bulk emails to my users. Some emails is marked as spam though. What can I do mitigate the spam marking?

code in PHP:

```
$ses = new AmazonSES();
$destination = array();
$destination['ToAddresses'] = $email;
$message = array();
$message['Subject.Data'] = "Domains: $contactsName have made a descision";
$message['Body.Text.Data'] = '';
$message['Body.Html.Data'] = "  Hi $firstName! 
                                </br>
                                </br> 
                                $contactsName have made a descision regarding $title at $link
                                </br>
                                </br>
                                Sincerely,
                                </br>
                                </br>
                                The Domain Team";
$message['Body.Html.Charset'] = 'utf-8';
$response = $ses->send_email('info@domain.com', $destination, $message);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many questions around this which will affect your spam reputation, but some quick ones:

1. How many users are you sending to (approximately)?
2. Do you always send emails to these users from this IP address?
3. Have your users opted-in to receive emails? Do they have an ongoing email relationship with you? Do they normally read emails that you send to them, or just delete them without looking?
4. Is your HTML valid? (From the above example, it appears than no - it should be `<br/>` not `</br>`.)

These are a few quick questions. The best quick advice I can give you is to make sure the users are opting-in, and encourage them to add you to their friend list. Try to send every email communication between you and them from Amazon SES.

Comment: In addition, make sure you set up an SPF record to avoid being filtered by your sender address. Check out http://www.openspf.org/. Even better would be to have a PTR record for the source IP in place that resolves to the domain name you use in your sender address, but I guess that won't be possible in your case.

Comment: +1 Very true. Entire blogs and careers are dedicated to this topic so the list is almost endless!

Comment: I would just like to point out that users of Amazon SES don't get a dedicated IP address. However, definitely have users opt-in, validate your HTML/CSS, and make sure you have a (working) unsubscribe link.

Comment: @JonLim Can you provide a reference to your statement that "Amazon SES don't get a dedicated IP address."?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Amazon SES, but I will have an attempt at this one.

There is an interesting discussion, specifically dealing with email sent through Amazon SES and getting marked as Spam here - [AWS Forum: "Email marked as spam CLOUDMARK"](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=226203)

Along with the points raised there, a couple of suggestions:

1. Always include a Text version of the content, some spam filters may interpret HTML-only emails as more likely to be spam (which they often are), plus some users may only have text-based email clients (some mobile users, etc.)
2. Check your spelling. Incorrect spelling is normally a dead giveaway for spam emails, and may result in people manually marking emails as spam without looking very closely.
3. (If possible.) Add a "From" Name. Again, if the email comes from a plain email address, rather than a Human-readable one which is appropriate to your message, it is more likely to look like spam (either to a filter or to a user).

Here is a suggested amended code (corrected spelling and HTML markup):

```
<?php
$ses = new AmazonSES();
$destination = array();
$destination['ToAddresses'] = $email;
$message = array();
$message['Subject.Data'] = "Domains: $contactsName have made a decision";
$message['Subject.Charset'] = 'UTF-8';

/* NOTE: Lines are broken for readability only */
$body = "Hi $firstName!<br>".
        "<br>".
        "$contactsName have made a decision regarding $title at $link<br>".
        "<br>".
        "Sincerely,<br>".
        "<br>".
        "The Domain Team";

$message['Body.Text.Data'] = str_replace( '<br>' , "\n" , $body );
$message['Body.Html.Data'] = $body;
$message['Body.Html.Charset'] = 'UTF-8';

$response = $ses->send_email('info@domain.com', $destination, $message);
```

Comment: Do you know how to add a from name in SES?

Comment: I am not certain, as I have not used Amazon SES. I would suggest running a test where you pass the destination in a format which most other mailing systems (like PHPMailer) allow like `$destination['ToAddresses'] = "John Doe <{$email}>";` and `$ses->send_email('Domain Info <info@domain.com>', ...`